# Scrape Anchored Website with Selenium Package in R

Tags: r, selenium, anchor-scroll

I am fairly new to R and am having trouble with pulling data from the Forbes website.

My current function is:

url =

```
http://www.forbes.com/global2000/list/#page:1_sort:0_direction:asc_search:_filter:All%20industries_filter:All%20countries_filter:All%20states
```

data = readHTMLTable(url)

However, the Forbes website is anchored with the "#" symbol within the link. I downloaded the rselenium package in order to parse the data I want, but I am not well versed with reselenium.

Does anyone have any advice/expertise with reselenium and how I can pull the data from Forbes using reselenium? Ideally I want to pull data from page 1, 2, etc. from the website.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little hacky, but here's my solution using rvest and read.delim...

```
library(rvest)

url <- "http://www.forbes.com/global2000/list/#page:1_sort:0_direction:asc_search:_filter:All%20industries_filter:All%20countries_filter:All%20states"
a <- html(url) %>%
  html_nodes("#thelist") %>%
  html_text()
con <- textConnection(a)
df <- read.delim(con, sep="\t", header=F, skip=12, stringsAsFactors=F)
close(con)
df$V1[df$V1==""] <- df$V3[df$V1==""]
df$V2 <- df$V3 <- NULL
df <- subset(df, V1!="")
df$index <- 1:nrow(df)
df2 <- data.frame(company=df$V1[df$index%%6==1],
                  country=df$V1[df$index%%6==2],
                  sales=df$V1[df$index%%6==3],
                  profits=df$V1[df$index%%6==4],
                  assets=df$V1[df$index%%6==5],
                  market_value=df$V1[df$index%%6==0])
```

Comment: Hey Cory. The function works to the extent that you are only looking at page 1 (see "#page:1" within the link). However, once you want to go to page 2, i.e. "#page:2",  the function does not work because it continues to pull data from page 1 due to the anchor. Any work around you can think of?

Answer (score 4):

Or another way using the API used to populate the webpage. This downloads all 2000 companies at one time.

```
library(httr)
library(RJSONIO)
url <- "http://www.forbes.com/ajax/load_list/"
query <- list("type" = "organization",
              "uri" = "global2000",
              "year" = "2014")
response <- httr::GET(url, query=query)
dat_string <- as(response, "character")
dat_list <- RJSONIO::fromJSON(dat_string, asText=TRUE)
df <- data.frame(rank = sapply(dat_list, "[[", 1),
                 company = sapply(dat_list, "[[", 3),
                 country=sapply(dat_list, "[[", 10),
                 sales=sapply(dat_list, "[[", 6),
                 profits=sapply(dat_list, "[[", 7),
                 assets=sapply(dat_list, "[[", 8),
                 market_value=sapply(dat_list, "[[", 9), stringsAsFactors=F)
df <- df[order(df$rank),]
```

Comment: Cory, you are a freaking genius! If/when you have the time, can you please explain: 1) how you found the API information for the webpage and 2) what httr and RJONSIO do? Any informational links on httr and RJONSIO will work to. I am definitely curious and want to learn how you got the API information. Thanks so much man!

Comment: Heh, thanks.
For finding the api... in chrome, right-click then choose "inspect element", Click the "network" tab then browse to the url. Click on the "/ajax/loadlist" entry and from there you can plug in the referrer and query string parameters you see there into the appropriate places in the R code. As for the httr and RJSONIO packages... google it!

Comment: Also one more thing, how did you specify the "list" function to be "organization", "global2000", and "2014"? Thanks!

Comment: Those were the query string parameters that were used for the api call. Got that info from "inspect element" -> network tab in chrome browser.

Comment: hi all. i am revisiting this issue after quite some time. I keep getting the following error when i run the code above provided by Cory:    
               
"Error in fromJSON(content, handler, default.size, depth, allowComments,  : invalid JSON input"

any ideas as to what the problem might be?  I have tried using other packages but have had no luck. any help would be great. thanks!